# BigInt to Bytes array in Dart

Tags: dart

I wanted to convert `BigInt` to `bytes[]` in flutter:

```
Function parseQrcode() {
    String _st =
        "6979414848205548481619299442879901900893978332594614407044767717485407280104077714658698163325401659212830920734233047578454701810567032015270223682917915825234703754712504887921309181789607809168884583848396456653007022479356336240198130363930881632367124738541517499494458139647378808680614169273221404741476596583953169248831376224396335169577064812987140578144885819479190173537644970232125142253963784979138011318798385442436099901621998283624816070080504830712594525760596934341576755626791590403636878139861665599383319429228364434183913197958738697001410493839281298692342829951566712530309758759364649701153639921979798429707566199261950037418171329283207372048014948669160666776198414040633384677104717697507521717586776709084200364956178863636105988867260929887577092955570407803783021397897341999914616790441029837229129746669225095633201097644321593502503404440714110515167034889128258965583435965030225845348564582051521348800742574442877087774194668983516629631073341202705453382780613775427336949283388084891654484225446940941660942440637784744293259916479841407088189462964489670231866481904237338494872813098890875845640034370370387108798950180220865436012752487216677041817312930119747601017807577565413977545693375480131324240696099879479436722576566447939593195590684591261809038023122178172006150499569185218838749337238281597037288924464009997530938336798176023597292328320965086990184531426188862965408313308973495924965144113396593829090645266653313774582036138982013368561474719154447134894466611560589758251829063226370300282175823479569847261439348404558251402273730865053482214589180028302043821438357583302818374143973997002745047526405755760407045006694423501337081780299815080324840337828812644300041900356816429114261098230198976752026002079876882796597235615015594486182057781476152918170746403157005216896239428521706033466061587608065036133153074432195952131368564234168005447770190345777024917629879639171161719929852078265309160759260989590618158889891835294735614366674503961584445497685736312628248483551986529867423016255476553691922054241686230968975229511700928171281549902682365302333677412951788839806869796040512235899311734337858684531156721416280114473368826463098485252394260075790386415875290922570568686439586036262465414002334117870088922801660529414759784318799843806130096998190881240404138869293309782335305296720666220243304175086358278211355789957998014801209332293458940463859106591986434520433810583569309224929264228263841477378949329312443958215939294432669464260216534074560882723006838459792812340253078330291135526952675203790833430237852831740601433198364243363569730205351077393441691141240055900819091229931605146865520183001810239708464322588389956036291760175558843819105418234580239610174323636606095262722940143706063698846499673285377621180570537788160304936809915237889489342387891057012783726694920184573202789672963922380028271124448024265644396686341508447830351380242127542393849410283830409594988503246799544444687606954881510597515686410993828907588979699141180160893062603338104857903239845856783130275935413569275439908789983311663211937449259444259898972766208";
    BigInt _bint = BigInt.parse(_st);
    // here I wanted to convert _bint to Bytes[]

  }
```

How to convert BigInt to `bytes[]` in flutter?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about how you want the bytes to be represented in the array but I have made the following solution and if there is anything wrong, please tell me:

```
import 'dart:typed_data';

void main() {
  parseQrcode();
}

void parseQrcode() {
  const _st =
      "6979414848205548481619299442879901900893978332594614407044767717485407280104077714658698163325401659212830920734233047578454701810567032015270223682917915825234703754712504887921309181789607809168884583848396456653007022479356336240198130363930881632367124738541517499494458139647378808680614169273221404741476596583953169248831376224396335169577064812987140578144885819479190173537644970232125142253963784979138011318798385442436099901621998283624816070080504830712594525760596934341576755626791590403636878139861665599383319429228364434183913197958738697001410493839281298692342829951566712530309758759364649701153639921979798429707566199261950037418171329283207372048014948669160666776198414040633384677104717697507521717586776709084200364956178863636105988867260929887577092955570407803783021397897341999914616790441029837229129746669225095633201097644321593502503404440714110515167034889128258965583435965030225845348564582051521348800742574442877087774194668983516629631073341202705453382780613775427336949283388084891654484225446940941660942440637784744293259916479841407088189462964489670231866481904237338494872813098890875845640034370370387108798950180220865436012752487216677041817312930119747601017807577565413977545693375480131324240696099879479436722576566447939593195590684591261809038023122178172006150499569185218838749337238281597037288924464009997530938336798176023597292328320965086990184531426188862965408313308973495924965144113396593829090645266653313774582036138982013368561474719154447134894466611560589758251829063226370300282175823479569847261439348404558251402273730865053482214589180028302043821438357583302818374143973997002745047526405755760407045006694423501337081780299815080324840337828812644300041900356816429114261098230198976752026002079876882796597235615015594486182057781476152918170746403157005216896239428521706033466061587608065036133153074432195952131368564234168005447770190345777024917629879639171161719929852078265309160759260989590618158889891835294735614366674503961584445497685736312628248483551986529867423016255476553691922054241686230968975229511700928171281549902682365302333677412951788839806869796040512235899311734337858684531156721416280114473368826463098485252394260075790386415875290922570568686439586036262465414002334117870088922801660529414759784318799843806130096998190881240404138869293309782335305296720666220243304175086358278211355789957998014801209332293458940463859106591986434520433810583569309224929264228263841477378949329312443958215939294432669464260216534074560882723006838459792812340253078330291135526952675203790833430237852831740601433198364243363569730205351077393441691141240055900819091229931605146865520183001810239708464322588389956036291760175558843819105418234580239610174323636606095262722940143706063698846499673285377621180570537788160304936809915237889489342387891057012783726694920184573202789672963922380028271124448024265644396686341508447830351380242127542393849410283830409594988503246799544444687606954881510597515686410993828907588979699141180160893062603338104857903239845856783130275935413569275439908789983311663211937449259444259898972766208";
  final _bint = BigInt.parse(_st);

  print(_bint.toRadixString(2));
  print(bigIntToUint8List(_bint)
      .map((i) => i.toRadixString(2).padLeft(8, '0'))
      .toList());
}

Uint8List bigIntToUint8List(BigInt bigInt) =>
    bigIntToByteData(bigInt).buffer.asUint8List();

ByteData bigIntToByteData(BigInt bigInt) {
  final data = ByteData((bigInt.bitLength / 8).ceil());
  var _bigInt = bigInt;

  for (var i = 1; i <= data.lengthInBytes; i++) {
    data.setUint8(data.lengthInBytes - i, _bigInt.toUnsigned(8).toInt());
    _bigInt = _bigInt >> 8;
  }

  return data;
}
```

This should give a byte array which looks the same as if we run `toRadixString(2)` on the `BigInt` just split up into bytes:

```
[00011111, 10001011, 00001000, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000, 00110011, 11111010, 01101111, 01100001, 01101001, 01100000, 01100001, 01100100, 01100000, 01101000, 01101001, 01100000, 01101100, 01100000, 01101010, 01101000, 01101010, 01100000, 01101000, 01101100, 01101110, 01101000, 01100100, 11111100, 00111111, 00100000, 00110101, 10101111, 00110100, 00110111, 10110001, 10101000, 00100100, 00100011, 01010011, 00100001, 00101100, 00110101, 00101111, 00111011, 10110001, 11100100, 10111111, 10000001, 10111001, 10101110, 10000001, 10101001, 10101110, 10100001, 10100101, 10000101, 11111001, 01111111, 11011111, 11111111, 11000001, 11111010, 11111110, 01010110, 00001010, 00000001, 10001001, 00100101, 00100101, 10001001, 01001001, 01000000, 00010101, 01000001, 10001001, 10111001, 10001001, 01000000, 00100010, 11111111, 10111111, 01101011, 01100010, 01110001, 10001001, 10000010, 01111011, 01111110, 01001010, 01100010, 01011001, 01100010, 01010001, 11100110, 01111111, 10111111, 11010100, 11000100, 00100010, 10000101, 11100000, 11001100, 10110010, 01000100, 10000101, 10010000, 11010100, 11011100, 10000010, 10011100, 11010100, 11111111, 00100110, 10111010, 00010110, 11000110, 11111111, 10000011, 10010011, 01001011, 11110010, 10001011, 01110100, 10001101, 11111110, 10011011, 00011010, 00011011, 00011011, 00011000, 10011010, 11111101, 01110111, 00101100, 01001010, 00101100, 11001001, 01001001, 11001100, 00000110, 00011001, 11110101, 11011111, 00110001, 00101111, 00100101, 10100011, 00101000, 01010001, 00100001, 10100000, 00101000, 00110001, 00100101, 10110101, 00111000, 11100011, 10111111, 01101111, 01100010, 01100110, 10011110, 01000010, 01010000, 01111110, 01100010, 11001010, 01111111, 11101111, 11000100, 10100010, 11000100, 10000010, 01000100, 00010100, 10110101, 11111111, 11111101, 11111111, 00000111, 00110010, 11101000, 00110011, 10000000, 10000000, 00001101, 00010100, 11000011, 00000000, 00101010, 10011111, 10011001, 10011101, 10010001, 00010001, 10000010, 11111110, 00000111, 00110001, 11110000, 00110000, 00110001, 00110000, 00110000, 00110010, 10110010, 10110010, 10110000, 00110000, 00110000, 11111100, 10001111, 01100001, 01010000, 01110110, 11001010, 10010111, 11001000, 01111011, 00000101, 10000100, 01111011, 11010010, 00011001, 11010010, 00011001, 11010010, 00011110, 11000101, 11111011, 00000000, 01100001, 10001010, 00000111, 00110011, 00010000, 10111010, 11111010, 01011111, 00000010, 11000010, 11000100, 11111111, 00101001, 00001100, 01001010, 00001100, 10001100, 11001110, 01000101, 10101001, 10001001, 00100101, 10101001, 00101001, 00001010, 01001001, 10010101, 01010110, 00001010, 01011110, 01011110, 01000110, 00000110, 00000110, 00000110, 00001010, 01100101, 10101001, 01000101, 11000101, 10011001, 11111001, 01111001, 00001010, 00100110, 01111010, 10000110, 11111111, 00100111, 00110000, 01110000, 10000001, 00101100, 01100010, 01111010, 11001110, 10000000, 01101110, 11000101, 11100100, 11111111, 00010011, 00011001, 10000000, 11110100, 11100001, 10001111, 10101100, 00111100, 11000010, 00110001, 11111010, 10001011, 11000000, 00111100, 11000110, 00000011, 10111111, 00011011, 00011101, 10111000, 00001111, 11001000, 10111100, 01010000, 00000001, 01110011, 10011001, 00001110, 01111110, 01100100, 11100110, 10011010, 11011000, 00001100, 01100110, 00110011, 00011111, 11111000, 01110101, 11100000, 11000001, 11101111, 11000110, 10000100, 01011111, 01001100, 00001100, 01101100, 11001010, 01000010, 11101100, 00111001, 11011010, 11000110, 00000110, 11111100, 00010001, 00101011, 11011110, 10000001, 11100101, 01011000, 00001110, 11010100, 00111000, 00111100, 10010000, 00010111, 10110000, 01100000, 01101100, 11100001, 01011101, 01110111, 10000001, 01101011, 10000010, 00011111, 11010011, 01101001, 10110000, 00110000, 11101011, 10000001, 10011010, 10000101, 00001010, 01110110, 00000001, 00000101, 11001100, 00000111, 00011001, 11111000, 11010010, 00111001, 10110110, 11110000, 10101000, 00011110, 11100000, 10011100, 00000101, 10010110, 01100000, 00111011, 11111100, 10011010, 10111011, 11111001, 10101001, 00100100, 11111011, 00101001, 00011101, 10010101, 01010100, 11111110, 01110010, 10101101, 01001110, 11001111, 00000101, 10010110, 01001100, 11000101, 10000010, 01111011, 01001111, 01101011, 01011010, 11110011, 00000110, 01100111, 10000111, 11111101, 11011100, 01110001, 01011101, 01010001, 11111101, 00001110, 11011111, 11011101, 10010000, 11000110, 00000111, 00011010, 01000001, 11011111, 11000001, 00011010, 11011000, 00001111, 01011000, 11011001, 00110000, 00011111, 01110001, 00010000, 01101100, 00010000, 00001101, 00111010, 01100000, 10011000, 10110111, 01110111, 10001010, 11011000, 01111101, 01011110, 10011001, 01010111, 11110111, 00101011, 10110110, 00001011, 11111101, 10110010, 00000101, 11001011, 01110011, 00011100, 10101000, 01010001, 01110001, 10101000, 01110001, 01001010, 10010000, 10010101, 10010000, 01110101, 01110101, 11111110, 11110100, 01010001, 01111001, 10001010, 10111011, 00000100, 10101011, 11101000, 00101101, 01111101, 01000001, 10110111, 00011111, 00110111, 00011001, 01101110, 11011111, 00010110, 00001001, 11100010, 00000100, 10101011, 11100010, 00111100, 11111100, 11011100, 10011110, 11111101, 01010100, 00010011, 11111111, 10000100, 00000101, 10000110, 10001100, 10000010, 00100101, 00111100, 11100111, 00011111, 01101111, 00110001, 11011011, 11001101, 10011101, 11110001, 10111110, 01101110, 01110111, 01000111, 11110000, 01010111, 10111011, 11110011, 01000111, 01100111, 00101001, 01111100, 11110001, 01111011, 01010010, 00111101, 10111001, 00101101, 10010110, 01001101, 11100100, 11000100, 01111100, 10010011, 11001100, 10110010, 11100010, 10001011, 11001110, 01010011, 01001101, 10111000, 00101010, 10101101, 00110111, 00001010, 11100101, 11011101, 11011101, 11111011, 01010010, 10010111, 10100001, 11110111, 10111001, 11110000, 10011101, 10010100, 01111101, 01001011, 00110011, 01011010, 00101100, 01000101, 10011101, 10111001, 01111000, 11011011, 01101110, 00011111, 00101100, 10011001, 10111111, 11000101, 00101001, 11101101, 11000011, 10001010, 11000100, 00111011, 01001111, 01100100, 11111010, 00001111, 10000010, 01101101, 11100000, 01011010, 00100000, 01110001, 01000000, 01101010, 11001101, 10110010, 00011101, 01011011, 10011101, 11000000, 01011100, 11101110, 00000011, 00101010, 00001100, 11100010, 10111110, 11100001, 00100101, 01100000, 00001110, 11001111, 11111001, 01000101, 11110011, 11111001, 11011011, 00011110, 11001001, 11110011, 01110010, 01110100, 01111100, 01011010, 11011000, 00101010, 11000111, 00111000, 00111011, 01011100, 11101101, 10100001, 11111100, 11010110, 11110101, 10010101, 00001011, 11101110, 11001111, 00001000, 01011010, 10011101, 11101001, 10111101, 11110010, 10000000, 11100110, 10011010, 10110101, 01110001, 01101100, 10001010, 01011010, 00001101, 00000001, 11101001, 10110110, 10000111, 01111000, 11011101, 01111111, 01011111, 10010001, 01111000, 01011001, 01101000, 00110011, 00111001, 00110000, 10101110, 01010101, 11100011, 01010111, 11111000, 01111101, 10100001, 01111110, 10101111, 01111101, 01011011, 01001011, 00001010, 00110111, 11111110, 11001001, 10101100, 00010001, 00111001, 10110001, 01100011, 01101111, 10111000, 01000111, 01011010, 01010110, 10010011, 11100111, 11100001, 11100110, 11111011, 11111111, 00111001, 10110101, 00111110, 11110000, 10011100, 01111100, 01111110, 11101110, 11000001, 11101001, 00110101, 10101011, 01111100, 11100111, 00110101, 10111000, 11100110, 01111101, 10110010, 01011111, 01110110, 01110011, 11111101, 11100111, 00001101, 01000010, 11101111, 10011110, 01001000, 00111100, 11011111, 10011110, 10100101, 10100111, 11011011, 11001001, 00010000, 00110101, 01000011, 01111001, 00110010, 11100011, 11010110, 10100101, 00110011, 01101100, 10001110, 01001010, 00011010, 10101111, 00101001, 11100011, 00010100, 11011000, 11111100, 00101000, 11110111, 11011010, 01000100, 10010011, 00111111, 11010111, 10011100, 11000101, 00011000, 01110111, 00101100, 01101101, 10001010, 01101111, 00111110, 10101111, 00011001, 10101010, 10101000, 11000100, 11000110, 01111000, 10011100, 11111001, 01001100, 10100101, 11011010, 10101011, 10001010, 01001101, 11011111, 01101101, 10000100, 01010111, 10110101, 01111101, 11011001, 00011101, 10100111, 01111010, 11101100, 00110001, 11011000, 11011001, 10111100, 00001101, 01100000, 10001010, 00001111, 01000010, 11110001, 00011111, 00111111, 11101001, 11011101, 01111110, 11101000, 10001011, 10011101, 01101000, 11000011, 00100101, 11001111, 00101011, 10000110, 10010110, 00100101, 10000111, 10010110, 11011001, 01000101, 00010100, 11001101, 01111101, 10011110, 10100010, 10111101, 00100000, 01000111, 01001011, 11100100, 01101101, 11101010, 10110100, 10001011, 10111111, 00000010, 00111010, 10011101, 11110111, 10100100, 11001111, 01011000, 11010011, 01111010, 01010001, 01101010, 11000001, 00011110, 10000111, 11010000, 11110101, 11001110, 01000110, 01010111, 10101111, 00100101, 11011111, 01110101, 01011010, 11110001, 11100010, 10111111, 11111100, 11110001, 00110010, 11010111, 10010100, 10101010, 01101000, 00100001, 11010001, 01110011, 01011001, 01111011, 00100110, 11101110, 01111100, 01110011, 11101100, 11010010, 11001111, 00100101, 01111010, 11000110, 01111011, 01011011, 00110111, 01011101, 01111111, 01110100, 11110011, 01011010, 01111000, 11010111, 10100110, 10101011, 00001111, 00111110, 00101010, 00001011, 11011100, 01111101, 10101100, 11110100, 01100010, 11110101, 11111011, 00101101, 10011101, 10100101, 00001111, 11010110, 11110000, 10011101, 10001001, 11111100, 10110111, 01100010, 11101011, 11001110, 10111111, 00110011, 11100100, 10011010, 01100110, 11111110, 11110110, 11111010, 01110110, 10011101, 01111011, 11011001, 11100001, 10001111, 10010011, 00100110, 10000110, 01111100, 01110100, 01111000, 01110011, 00111000, 00101001, 00111110, 00110100, 00000110, 11101100, 00011010, 00000001, 10001000, 10100011, 00000100, 00011011, 11111110, 11011111, 10010100, 00110111, 11111100, 00111000, 11101011, 10001111, 11110110, 10011010, 10111101, 01011101, 10111111, 01011011, 10000010, 10110010, 10011110, 11011100, 10010010, 11110000, 01010010, 01010111, 01111111, 01110001, 01101000, 11100011, 10110110, 10011101, 00101011, 11100100, 01111100, 10001111, 01101101, 11110111, 11001101, 11010100, 10010010, 11011000, 11001011, 10010111, 00111101, 11001011, 10101101, 10101001, 00111100, 00111101, 10111100, 10110100, 11111000, 11001110, 00001010, 10010110, 10101111, 01100010, 01000010, 00000101, 00010001, 11110111, 11001110, 00010111, 01101110, 11101000, 10011010, 01101011, 00010110, 10101110, 11010011, 11001000, 10111101, 11101110, 11111010, 10001011, 10110101, 01001011, 10100111, 10101111, 01001010, 11110010, 11111111, 01101111, 10111000, 00111100, 11101100, 11101111, 01100101, 11011110, 10010010, 00001101, 00100110, 01010001, 01110001, 01010001, 10001111, 10111110, 01001011, 00101100, 10101000, 00101011, 00010000, 11101100, 01001011, 11011011, 11011011, 00100110, 00111011, 01110001, 00001001, 11001111, 01001100, 10010001, 11001100, 11000111, 10111101, 01110101, 11001001, 01010111, 11111111, 00101110, 11111111, 11101011, 00010100, 10110011, 01011000, 11001101, 01101100, 10110101, 01111111, 01110000, 11011111, 00101101, 01101011, 11001101, 10010000, 11001100, 11011111, 01111011, 11101110, 01001111, 01011010, 10100010, 01010010, 10110011, 00100010, 10111100, 11101000, 01101000, 10101001, 11111001, 11001100, 11011101, 10101011, 00100011, 10011001, 01001100, 01010110, 00110100, 10011101, 00110111, 01011100, 01110100, 11100110, 11010011, 10101110, 11111100, 10001000, 00011001, 11101101, 10000101, 10000110, 00001001, 11000001, 11011110, 10101111, 10110100, 01111001, 11001011, 10001101, 10101110, 11111101, 01011101, 01110010, 01010010, 10011110, 10101101, 11000111, 11011100, 01101010, 10110111, 11000100, 11101001, 01011001, 01011011, 00011000, 01101111, 01111001, 01101111, 00001100, 01111011, 11001111, 01111001, 00101001, 01111001, 11001011, 11001001, 01110111, 00010011, 10100100, 11110011, 01011000, 01001110, 00100111, 00001000, 11110011, 01000101, 10100101, 01011000, 00101000, 00111110, 10111000, 10010110, 10111111, 10000100, 10100101, 11100100, 01000000, 11101100, 11101111, 00110111, 01101001, 10110111, 00101101, 10101110, 01100110, 00111000, 00110111, 11110100, 00010101, 00111110, 01110000, 01111000, 10101100, 10110110, 11111011, 11010001, 01100011, 11111111, 00110101, 00010111, 11110101, 10111111, 00101000, 01101111, 01100111, 10111001, 11110111, 11001111, 00110100, 11100110, 11010001, 00101100, 11011111, 10110010, 11111101, 00001011, 11111100, 01111000, 00000100, 01010011, 10110110, 00011110, 01100111, 11011111, 10011010, 01111001, 10001010, 11010001, 01011111, 01011000, 11000000, 01000011, 00110100, 01110110, 10110111, 11010001, 10101100, 00001011, 01110011, 11101111, 11110011, 00011110, 11011101, 00110011, 11011101, 01100111, 11010110, 10110110, 11010111, 01011111, 00100011, 01111110, 01001111, 00001010, 01010001, 01010001, 11110100, 10111010, 00001100, 00000000, 11011010, 01011111, 11101001, 10001011, 01001100, 00000101, 00000000, 00000000]
```